# JSF2, Ajax partial update and ui repeat - submit and update dynamically added text boxes

Tags: html, ajax, jsf-2, validation

I have a JSF2 application and a page with the following code:

```
<h:inputText id="someInput" required="true" />

<p:outputPanel id="itemsPanel">
    <ui:repeat var="i" value="#{myBean.itemIndices}" id="items">
        <h:inputText 
            id="itemInput" 
            value="#{myBean.dataItems[i]}" 
            />
        <h:panelGroup 
            layout="block" 
            styleClass="clear" 
            rendered="#{((i+1) % 10 == 0)}" 
            />
    </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
<br/>
<p:commandButton
    classStyle="btn" 
    value="Add Row"
    actionListener="#{myBean.increaseItemsCount}" 
    update="itemsPanel" 
    immediate="false"
    ajax="true"
    />
```

The `ui:repeat` is dynamically rendering a number if text boxes depending on the `itemIndices` and `dataItems` properties. The "Add Row" button calls a method that will dynamically increase the number of `itemIndices` and `dataItems`, therefore additional text inputs appear.

The current code will not work if there is no value in the text box `someInput`, because the AJAX request also validates the form and validation fails. Pressing the button in this case has no visual effect, not even feedback for the user that validation did not pass (because I update `itemsPanel` only).

If I change the button to have `immediate="true"`, then the validation issue is no more. Unfortunately, I want to be able to restore the values of the dynamic input fields that the user might have changed prior adding the new row. The `immediate="true"` attribute causes the form not to be submitted to the server, therefore the user-entered data will not be persisted.

A possible solution to this could be to add `process="all dynamic input ids csv"` attribute to the command button and set the `immediate` attribute back to `true`. This will cause the server to validate only the inputs specified in the process attribute and they will be persisted. The problem here is that these input ids are dynamically generated by JSF and I cannot come up with a proper way to get them as a CSV. I would also not prefer a solution for dynamically generating ids in `myBean` relying on assumptions of how JSF would output them.

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yep good ol' Ceburashka buddy

Comment: What is the scope of your bean ?

Comment: @mmanco View scope, but this is not something I am going to change because I do not need that bean to keep state. Also, I am not sure if the bean scope has anything to do with the issue I am facing. Still, if you have any suggestions with the scope, feel free to share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `process="itemsPanel"`.

```
<p:commandButton
    classStyle="btn" 
    value="Add Row"
    actionListener="#{myBean.increaseItemsCount}" 
    process="itemsPanel" 
    update="itemsPanel" 
    ajax="true"
    />
```

You should only move the command button into `<h:outputPanel id="itemsPanel">`.

Comment: It works, but only if I put the command button inside items panel. Just mention it in your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: I edited the answer above, I just did not know that I can do it with other people's posts.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov I bumped into a similar problem. What I observed was, strangely enough but basically the component itself needs to be submitted/processed for its actionListener to be invoked. 
Alternatively you can just add `@this` to the `process`
`process="itemsPanel, @this"` in Primefaces